# How to delete duplicates in a table in snowflake, but leaving only one row?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to eliminate the duplicates of a table in snowflake, but there's an issue that I can't solve.

I'm using this code:

```
DELETE FROM int_ga.DIM_table
WHERE id  ,  in (
  SELECT id  
  FROM (
      SELECT SK_DIM_CHANNEL
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id  , name ORDER BY id  ) AS rn
      FROM int_ga.DIM_table
  )
  WHERE rn > 1
);
```

Imagine this example table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | example1 |
| 1 | example1 |
| 2 | example2 |
| 3 | example3 |
| 3 | example3 |

It's supposed to be like this:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | example1 |
| 2 | example2 |
| 3 | example3 |

But in the end, it eliminates both of the duplicates. I can't make it only delete one of them.

Answer (score 3):

In scenario like this, when there is no unique id an alternative approach of reinserting all rows is possible(if table is relatively small):

```
INSERT OVERWRITE INTO int_ga.DIM_table(id, name) 
SELECT id, name
FROM int_ga.DIM_table 
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY name) = 1;
```

More intrusive way is to recreate entire table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE int_ga.DIM_table 
COPY GRANTS
AS
SELECT *
FROM int_ga.DIM_table 
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY name) = 1;
```

---

The windowed function is not stable:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, name ORDER BY id  )
```

as the `ORDER BY id` is always the same(column id is already being used for partitioning.

If the goal is to leave single entry only per `id` then it should be rather:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY <some_column>)
```